# o($n \log n$) algorithm for a noncrossing matching in plane

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, discrete-geometry

I am thinking about the algorithm for the following well-known mathematical problem.

- $n$ red points and $n$ blue points in the plane in general position are given.
  Find the matching $\{r_1, b_1\}, \ldots, \{r_n, b_n\}$ such that no two line segments $r_ib_i$ and $r_jb_j$ cross.

I came up with the following divide and conquer method:

1. Draw a line $\ell$ which simultaneously divides red points and blue points equally (Ham Sandwich Theorem guarantees the exitence).
2. Solve the problem recursively for each side of $\ell$

Surprisingly, there are O($n$) algorithm for Step 1 (see  http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2002/DanielleMacNevin/algorithm-pg1.html).
Therefore the time complexity is O($n \log n$) in total.

Is there a faster algorithm than this?

Comment: I don't know. But here's another way. Make any matching of red and blue points. If $r_1b_1$ crosses $r_2b_2$ then replace those two segments with $r_1b_2$ and $r_2b_1$. This is guaranteed to decrease the sum of the lengths of the segments. Keep doing this as long as there are crossing segments. The process must terminate, since the sum of lengths can't decrease forever.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That will be another proof for the existence. 
But it seems to take much time for worst case.
Computing the minimum length matching takes O($n^3$) time by using maximum weighted bipartite matching algorithm.